# Solr: How to pass a multivalued request parameter as a "local parameter" in a nested query?

Tags: solr, dismax, subquery

I am constructing a nested Solr DisMax query of the format: `_query_:"{!edismax qf=...}...`. Now I need to add several boosting queries (bq-parameter), but simply writing `_query_:"{!edismax qf=... bq=foo bq=bar}` doesn't seem to work as only one of the bq-keys is processed and the rest are ignored. Is it possible to pass multivalued parameters as [LocalParams](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multivalued local parameters turned out to be not implemented at the moment.
Here's a CR for that - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2798

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using localparams and complicating the query try using a new request handler.
The multiple bq parameters can be specified easily and should work fine and should be easier to understand.

```
<requestHandler name="edismax" class="solr.SearchHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="qf">
            title
        </str>
        <str name="bq">
            foo bar
        </str>
        <str name="fl">
            *,score
        </str>
        <int name="ps">100</int>
        <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    </lst>   
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: I cannot use this approach because the query is a dynamically generated nested Solr query and I have to use QParserPlugin and LocalParams. The entire query looks this way: `q=+(_query:"{!edismax ...}...") +(_query:"{!edismax ...}...") etc`. Each nested query has a different "qf", "bq", "mm" and other parameters.